# Automatic color change/remember

Tags: java, timer, background-color, swingworker

Trying to make something like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPU6mnM2i-k

Different panels (in which I later on put letters and probably change them into JButtons) are picked by pressing Stop button. I changed it action by adding a variable counting how many times it got pressed. Not the ideal thing but works. I would like to clean the code a little bit but I am not sure how to do it. Not sure if I shouldn't put SwingWorker somewhere and try to use one Timer instead of three. All panels are held in JPanels arrays. It was supposed to make code cleaner but apparently it made it exactly the other way around. The program works but it looks kind of awful. Please help.

```
private final JPanel[] firstLevelPanels = new JPanel[2];
private final JPanel[] secondLevelPanels1 = new JPanel[3];
private final JPanel[] secondLevelPanels2 = new JPanel[3];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels1 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels2 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels3 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels4 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels5 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[] rowPanels6 = new JPanel[7];
private final JPanel[][] allPanels = new JPanel[9][];
private int currentlyActivePanel = 0;
private int activeAncestorPanel = 0;
private int stopCounter = 0;
private int counter = 0;

class FirstLevelAction implements ActionListener{

    JPanel[] panel;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        changeBackground(allPanels[activeAncestorPanel], counter);
        counter = (counter+1)%2;
    }

    public FirstLevelAction(JPanel[][] panels, int panelNumber) {

        this.panel = panels[panelNumber];
    } 
}

class SecondLevelAction implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{

    JPanel[] tempPanel;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        changeBackground(allPanels[activeAncestorPanel], counter);
        counter = (counter+1)%3;
    }

    public SecondLevelAction(JPanel[][] panels, int panelNumber) {

        this.tempPanel = panels[panelNumber];
    }       
}

class ThirdLevelAction implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{

    JPanel[] tempPanel;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        changeBackground(allPanels[activeAncestorPanel], counter);
        counter = (counter+1)%7;
    }

    public ThirdLevelAction(JPanel[][] panels, int panelNumber) {

        this.tempPanel = panels[panelNumber];
    }       
}

private void changeBackground(JPanel[] panels, int panelIndex){

    for(JPanel panel : panels){
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }
    panels[panelIndex].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    currentlyActivePanel = panelIndex;
}

private Timer timer1 = new Timer(500, new FirstLevelAction(allPanels, activeAncestorPanel));
private Timer timer2;
private Timer timer3;

private void stopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    stopCounter++;
    counter = 0;
    if(stopCounter == 1){
        timer1.stop();
        activeAncestorPanel = currentlyActivePanel + 1;
        allPanels[0][currentlyActivePanel].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        currentlyActivePanel = 0;
        timer2 = new Timer(500, new SecondLevelAction(allPanels, activeAncestorPanel));
        timer2.start();
    }else if(stopCounter == 2){
        timer2.stop();
        allPanels[activeAncestorPanel][currentlyActivePanel].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        activeAncestorPanel = activeAncestorPanel + activeAncestorPanel*2 + currentlyActivePanel;
        currentlyActivePanel = 0;
        timer3 = new Timer(500, new ThirdLevelAction(allPanels, activeAncestorPanel));
        timer3.start();
    }else{
        timer3.stop();
        stopCounter = 0;
        allPanels[activeAncestorPanel][currentlyActivePanel].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        activeAncestorPanel = 0;
        timer1 = new Timer(500, new FirstLevelAction(allPanels, activeAncestorPanel));
        timer1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create your own subtype of JPanel, which is composed of the possible colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state machine structure by using case-switching and a list of states to transition between. Take a look at the oracle docs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Basically you want each active panel to be set to its corresponding number on initialization like this:

```
     private static final int activePanelState = activePanel1;//whatever is default
     private static final int activePanel1 = 1;
     private static final int activePanel2 = 2;
     private static final int activePanel3 = 3;
```

Then switch between these states and call the correct jPanel functions within each case as well as setting the correct transition:

eg.

```
switch(activePanelState){
     case activePanel1:
         jPanel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
         jPanel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
         activePanelState = activePanel2;
        break;
```

and so on.

Comment: I guess it is ok but don't you think that using a switch method is a sign of bad programming? I mean ye I can make switch with 100 cases but is it really the best way to do it? Also I am not sure how to start a timer again with SwingWorker class. Should I make new timer for each "level of panels"? So one for two beginning panels, then one for next three and so on? Thought about using one but it also be about switching between different switch methods. If then I have 3 different Timers another issue I have is how to stop them? I want to have only one stop button for the whole program.